$\int_0^\pi \frac1{1-x\cos \theta-y\sin \theta}+\frac1{1+x\cos \theta+y\sin\theta}d\theta=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}$
My question is: how can we prove the following integral equation? For any $x,y\in \mathbb R$ such that $x^2+y^2<1$,
$$
\int_0^\pi d\theta\left(\frac1{1-x\cos \theta-y\sin \theta}+\frac1{1+x\cos \theta+y\sin\theta} \right)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}.
$$Here is where the equation comes from. Consider the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\qquad (x^2+y^2<1)$$This function has an interesting property; the line integral of $f$ over any straight line which intersects the unit circle is always equal to $1$ (it is a good calculus exercise to prove this). This implies that $f$ has a simple  Radon transform. That is, letting $\mathcal Rf(t,\theta)$ be the integral of $f$ over the line whose distance to the origin is $t$, and where the closest point to the origin has an angle of $\theta$, then $\mathcal R f(t,\theta)$ is equal to $1$ when $t\le 1$ and zero otherwise. I then applied the formula for the inverse Radon transform given in this quesiton to $\mathcal Rf(t,\theta)$. If the inversion formula works correctly, we should get the original function back, hence the above equation.
However, this is not a rigorous proof. The Radon inversion formula came with an assumption on $f$; it only applies if $f$ is in the Schwarz space of rapidly decaying functions. Instead, $f(x,y)$ explodes rapidly, and has a singularity over the whole boundary of the unit disk, so I see no reason the inversion formula should apply here. In fact, since the formula involves $\frac{d}{dt} \mathcal Rf(t,\theta)$, but my $\mathcal Rf(t,\theta)$ is not continuous, I had to assume a generalized derivative to apply the formula, which I think is not justified. Still, I have numerically evaluated the above integral with Mathematica, and it appears to be correct. I am wondering, therefore, if there is a simpler proof of this integral that does not require understanding Radon transforms.

Could the Weierstrass substitution be used?

Observe we have the integral
\begin{align}
 I=\int^\pi_0 \frac{2 d\theta}{1-(x\cos t+y\sin t)^2}\ .
\end{align}
Next, notice that
\begin{align}
x\cos t+y\sin t= \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \sin(\theta+\delta)
\end{align}
for some $\delta$ dependent on $x, y$. Hence this means that
\begin{align}
I = \int^\pi_0 \frac{2 d\theta}{1-(x^2+y^2)\sin^2(\theta+\delta)} =  \int^{\pi}_0 \frac{2d\theta}{1-(x^2+y^2)\sin^2(\theta)}
\end{align}
where the last equality follows from periodicity.  Then it follows
\begin{align}
I = \int^{\pi}_0 \frac{2d\theta}{1-x^2-y^2+(x^2+y^2)\cos^2(\theta)} = \int^{\pi}_0 \frac{2\sec^2(\theta)d\theta}{(1-x^2-y^2)\sec^2(\theta)+(x^2+y^2)}=\int^{\pi}_{0} \frac{2\sec^2(\theta)d\theta}{1+(1-x^2-y^2)\tan^2(\theta)}=\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \frac{2\sec^2(\theta)d\theta}{1+(1-x^2-y^2)\tan^2(\theta)}
\end{align}
where the last equality also follows from periodicity.
Finally, set $t=\tan(\theta)$, then we have
\begin{align}
I= \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{2d t}{1+(1-x^2-y^2)t^2} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}.
\end{align}

Using the Weierstrass substitution, $t=\tan\frac12\theta$, the integral becomes $$\begin{align}&\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{1-x\cdot\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-y\cdot\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}+\frac1{1+x\cdot\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+y\cdot\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}\right)\cdot\frac2{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\=&\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{2}{(1+x)t^2-2yt+(1-x)}+\frac2{(1-x)t^2+2yt+(1+x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\=&\frac2{1+x}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{t^2-\frac{2y}{1+x}t+\frac{1-x}{1+x}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t+\frac2{1-x}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{t^2+\frac{2y}{1-x}t+\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\=&\frac2{1+x}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{\left(t-\frac{y}{1+x}\right)^2+\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{(1+x)^2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t+\frac2{1-x}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{\left(t+\frac{y}{1-x}\right)^2+\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{(1-x)^2}}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t\\=&\frac2{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{(1+x)\left(t-\frac{y}{1+x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{(1-x)\left(t+\frac{y}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right)\right]_0^\infty\\=&\frac2{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\left(\frac\pi2+\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\right)\right)\\=&\boxed{\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}}\end{align}$$
